# Differences between Orthodox, Conservative, and Reform Judaism

Tags: heterodox, orthodox

Is there a good reference that gives major differences between the practices of Orthodox, Conservative, and Reform Judaism?

Comment: In the last couple of years, the differences between Reform and Conservative Judaism has blurred.  A big reason for that was when the Rabbinical Assembly of the Conservative movement voted to not only permit gay marriages, but to justify it by saying that the Torah laws are not Divine.  That is a major change for the movement which used to hold that, at least, the laws in the Written Torah were from G-d and should be observed, but that the rabbinic laws were fair game to be revised.  Now it appears that any change in Torah law is fair game to tehm, also.

Comment: More specific: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/135944

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jewish_religious_movements#Modern_movements_or_denominations) what you are looking for?

Comment: link no longer works (due to restructuring of wikipedia page?), is this the information you were getting at?: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relationships_between_Jewish_religious_movements

Comment: @Menachem I think I found what he was referring to. (Not that I condone Wikipedia links as answers.)

Comment: @DoubleAA, I don't condone WP (or other) links as answers when the question asks for a substantive answer. Here, the question asks for a *reference*, and that's precisely what the answer provides.

Answer (score 3):

I don't know of one specific book or article, but reading these 4 articles would probably give you a good feel for the major religious differences.

1. http://judaism.about.com/od/denominationsofjudaism/p/branches.htm
2. http://www.jewishvirtuallibrary.org/jsource/Judaism/conservatives.html
3. http://www.jewishvirtuallibrary.org/jsource/Judaism/reform_practices.html
4. http://www.jewishvirtuallibrary.org/jsource/Judaism/Orthodox.html

Answer (score 2):

http://www.world-religions-professor.com/orthodox-jews.html

this is what you are looking for most likely

Comment: Welcome to Mi Yodeya, and thanks for bringing this resource! Could you please [edit] this post, in light of [this guidance](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer) from our Help Center? *Links to external resources are encouraged, but please add context around the link so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there. Always quote the most relevant part of an important link, in case the target site is unreachable or goes permanently offline.*

Comment: @IsaacMoses http://mi.yodeya.com/posts/comments/103162